# SharePoint 2010 List Schema.XML not working as imagined

Tags: list, sharepoint-2010, field

I am created an External List in VS and in the schema.XML file I have a few fields that I would like to change their display name, and format some dates.

We created an External List in SP, exported the wsp, and grabbed the list components of the site and added it to our project.

Here is an example of what I thought would work, but it does not.

```
<Field DisplayName="Date Closed" Format="DateOnly" Hidden="FALSE" Name="DateClosed" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" StaticName="DateClosed" Type="DateTime" />
<Field DisplayName="Closed By" Hidden="FALSE" Name="ClosedBy" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" StaticName="ClosedBy" Type="Text" />
```

We have a filter setup in the  section which is working, so I know that the file is being used.  Any insight as to why the changes I made to the field are not taking effect?